# insertar un registro con id autoincrementable php

Tags: php, mvc, crud

Tengo el siguiente código para insertar un registro en mi base de datos:

```
public function insertarEmpleado($empleado)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO empleado values(:nombre, :apellidos, :email, :departamento, :costeHora, :foto)");
    $stmt->bindValue('nombre',$empleado->getNombre());
    $stmt->bindValue('apellidos',$empleado->getApellidos());
    $stmt->bindValue('email',$empleado->getEmail());
    $stmt->bindValue('departamento',$empleado->getDepartamento());
    $stmt->bindValue('costeHora',$empleado->getCosteHora());
    $stmt->bindValue('foto',$empleado->getFoto());
    $resultadoRegistro = $stmt->execute();
    if($resultadoRegistro) {
        return $this->db->lastInsertId();
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

La tabla en cuestión es la siguiente:

```
create table empleado(
  id integer not null primary key auto_increment,
  nombre varchar(255),
  apellidos varchar(255),
  email varchar(255),
  departamento varchar(255),
  costeHora decimal(5,2),
  foto varchar(255)
);
```

Hay un campo id que es primary key y autoincrementable. Al ser autoincrementable, no lo incluyo en el insert, sin embargo, cuando ejecuto, me da error. Me dice que la primera columna no corresponde. Alguien sabe donde está el error?

Answer (score 0):

El bindValue tiene que ir con `:` delante

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO empleado values(:nombre, :apellidos, :email, :departamento, :costeHora, :foto)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':nombre',$empleado->getNombre());
    $stmt->bindValue(':apellidos',$empleado->getApellidos());
    $stmt->bindValue(':email',$empleado->getEmail());
    $stmt->bindValue(':departamento',$empleado->getDepartamento());
    $stmt->bindValue(':costeHora',$empleado->getCosteHora());
    $stmt->bindValue(':foto',$empleado->getFoto());
```

Comment: Nada, lo he puesto con : delante del parámetro y me sigue diciendo lo mismo: 

ErrorSQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado. Problemas de sintaxis:

```
public function insertarEmpleado($empleado)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO empleado (idEmpleado, nombre, apellidos, email, departamento, costeHora, foto) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindValue(1,$empleado->getIdEmpleado());
    $stmt->bindValue(2,$empleado->getNombre());
    $stmt->bindValue(3,$empleado->getApellidos());
    $stmt->bindValue(4,$empleado->getEmail());
    $stmt->bindValue(5,$empleado->getDepartamento());
    $stmt->bindValue(6,$empleado->getCosteHora());
    $stmt->bindValue(7,$empleado->getFoto());
    $resultadoRegistro = $stmt->execute();
    if($resultadoRegistro) {
        return $this->db->lastInsertId();
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias!!